# check if a value already exists in a Hash Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

have a method in which I'm trying to iterate through the values of a HashMap and to check if they match a specific string - if they do, then I want the method to return false. I had a look at a few topics and this is what I've come up with although it does not seem to work:

```
class Person { 

public int check(String newName, String newNumber) {

        for (Person recordObject : map.values()) {

            if (map.get(recordObject) != null
                    && map.get(recordObject).toString().equals(newNumber)) {

                return 0;
            }
        }

        map.put(newName, newNumber);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

At the moment my program always creates a record for some person, even if they have already been added to the map so it does not actually go into the if of the check method.

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` is not enough information. tells us more about your input, output and what you expect

Comment: also "check" is not a good method name IMHO. at least put some javadoc above it

Comment: this is an unfinished program, I just want to know how to correctly check if a value already exists in a HashMap so please don't post useless comments. I've only renamed this method due to possible risk of plagiarism/collusion as this is my school project. If you look at the bottom of the post, I have explained what is happening.

Comment: @user3281466 What's your mapping (`Person -> Person`)? On one side you're using `map.get(recordObject)` which assumes that your keys in the map are Person objects, but in the other hand you're doing `map.put(name, record);` (is `name` a String?). Could you clarify that please?

Comment: @user3281466 don't get rude! my 2 comments are anything but useless!

Comment: +1 to encourage! Why do we see downvotes this much these days? It's mechanism should change for sure!

Comment: @ZouZou Hey, yes name is a String. I know it seems a bit messy, I will try to explain - so my Person class has 2 fields - an object and a number (don't worry about the object, it's basically because I may need to use some of the getter methods which are defined in a separate class). The check method is defined in the Person class and here is also where I am putting things I want in the map. so the map would contain String keys and Person values. Hope this makes a bit more sense

Comment: @user3281466 So how would you expect that `map.get(recordObject)` does not return `null`? `get` will return you the value mapped with the key in your map or `null` if there is no such mapping for the specified key. But you're using `String` as key and here you call get with a `Person` object. So `map.get(recordObject) != null` will never be true. Hence you're always adding the new record to the map.

Comment: @user3281466 Your approach seems to be correct (while not very optimal) but it should work (assuming  `map.put(name, record);` should be  `map.put(newName, record);`). See this: http://ideone.com/CNIuTn. So not sure if the problem is really here.

Comment: @ZouZou Hey, I found what the problem is, basically for some reason every time I call the method the map is empty for some reason. Would it be possible to have a look at my code in a private chat for something as I cannot post it here (due to risk of plagiarism).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your checking if a value in the map is also a key in the map...

```
 for (Person object : map.values()) {

                if (map.get(object) != null
                        && map.get(object).getNumber().equals(newNumber)) {

                    return false;
                }
            }
```

I assume that your mapping is (String) Name -> (Person) person, by

```
map.put(name, record);
```

Is this an ideal mapping? What if people have the same name?

If you want to see if the map has the same key can you not simply use the method
`boolean personExistsInMap = map.containsKey(String name)`?

EDIT

Another possible implementation then is do have a `Set<Person>`, and get away from the HashMap since it seems like having a `name` as the key is rather pointless. You could then override your equals method in `Person`.

```
Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<Person>();

if(personSet.contains(Person)) {
//Bla Bla
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why I haven't used containsKey, basically every person has a number which is stored in a Person object. So before I put a key and a value in the HashMap I want to check if the value.getNumber() has not already been added.

Comment: I think I will still need to use the key later on, I'm afraid, but thanks anyway.

Comment: This can be a case i.e. if he is counting number of persons having same name

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over `map.values()` but then you're using those values as keys; either iterate over the keys with `map.keySet()` and use `map.get(key)` or just use the values you get with `map.values()` without another `map.get(object)`.

Comment: In principle that should be correct; there may be other problems of course. The best way to find your error is probably to debug the code and set a breakpoint into that if expression. That way you'll hopefully find out, why the numbers aren't found.

Comment: Mind you, if possible using the numbers as keys would probably be an easier solution, that way you could use `map.containsKey(newNumber)`.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I definitely need to store a name as the key and a person object as the values as I will need this for further implementation of the functionality of the program.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `HashMap<String,Person>` to store your people, and also a `HashSet<String>` to store the numbers.  For each new `Person`, use the `add` method of the `HashSet` to add the number, but check the return value.  If it's false, the number was already in the `HashSet`, so you shouldn't add the `Person` to the `HashMap`.  If it's true, go ahead and add the `Person` to the `HashMap`.  It might look something like this.

```
public class PersonRegister {
    public Map<String,Person> personsByName = new HashMap<String,Person>();
    public Set<String> numbers = new HashSet<String>();

    public void addPerson(Person toAdd) {
        if (numbers.add(toAdd.getNumber())) {
            personsByName.put(toAdd.getName(), toAdd);
        }
    }

    // and some more methods, no doubt.
}
```